# Why does fmt.FPrintf(...) take in io.Writer instead of *io.Writer?

Tags: go, pointers, interface

Consider the following function signature:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w io.Writer, format string, a ...any) (n int, err error)
```

Q1: Why is the first parameter `io.Writer` and not `*io.Writer`?

Q2: Since it is `io.Writer`, is it possible to pass in a value that will not actually write to the location that the caller expected?

Comment: Because you "never" use pointers to interfaces.

Comment: `*io.Writer` is a pointer type with no methods, not an interface.

Comment: @Volker Although I agree with the general sentiment of your comment, "never" should be nuanced. Pointers to an interface value are occasionally useful, esp. for unmarshaling JSON whose structure isn't known in advance: https://go.dev/play/p/5FvxvwD04cy

Comment: @jub0bs: Did you se the quotation marks? Somebody like the OP who is clearly struggling with types and pointers needs a simple, easy to follow advice.

Comment: @Volker I did see the quotation marks, but I wasn't sure what you used them for, distance or emphasis.

Answer (score 3):

1. `io.Writer` is an interface type. A pointer type typically implements an interface. But the function simply sees an interface value. It shouldn't care about its implementation details.
2. Yes, `io.Discard` is a no-op writer. Note, that the function should not have assumptions about the actual location where the data are written to.